# максимальная длина ответа от сервер XMLHttpRequest в формате json

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

у меня есть функция которая отправляет данные на сервер через XMLHttpRequest, а сервер возвращает ответ в формате json

какова максимальная длина ответа в плане символов? если допустим ответ состоит из 100 строковых значений, и каждое значение по ~30 символов то, это будет примерно 3000+ символов в запросе, каковы ограничения? Зависит это от сервера или от самого клиента как принимающей стороны?

Comment: [Для ajax: нет ограничения, кроме установленного на сервере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392847/2881286)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если браузер не указал обратного ограничений на размеры переменных нет.

Для AJAX: нет ограничений, кроме тех, которые установлены на сервере.

<sub>Перевод ответа [@Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392847/2881286)</sub>